Drives not recognising as NVME
We recently bought PowerEdge Server.
It has RAID/Internal Storage Controllers (PERC H755N Front). We have 3.2Tb NVME harddisk but they are recognised as SSD in the Ubuntu 22.04 operating system we installed.
Any suggestions please.

Since you just purchased them and Dell does support Ubuntu on some of their machines would this not be a better question for them?


We have 3.2Tb NVME harddisk but they are recognised as SSD

It's not clear how many drives you're talking about.
If it's one drive, and it's being recognized as an SSD: that seems right.
If it's one drive, and it's not being recognized: try and switch the RAID controller's mode to AHCI.
If it's more than one drive (and you want to use them in a RAID configuration): you'll have to set up a RAID configuration in the BIOS / UEFI first, creating at least one RAID volume.
If it's more than one drive (and you don't want to use them in a RAID configuration): again try and switch the RAID controller's mode to AHCI.
IIRC PowerEdges come with some sort of management tool (a webserver) that you can access to do stuff remotely (no idea if that allows setting up the RAID controller's mode / a RAID configuration); if in housing you may ask your provider to connect some KVM devices to the servers. But if you're in physical presence obviously you could just access the BIOS / UEFI.
